# Make SVG Image ignore parent viewBox

Tags: svg, viewbox

I have image inside svg with viewBox, is it possible to make image ignore scaling caused by viewBox and always keep size image 50x50?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <image xlink:href="someimage.png" width="50" height="50"></image>
</svg>
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LpxV/1/

Comment: Just delete the viewBox attribute. If there's more to it than that you should explain what that is.

Comment: There are a lot of other elements which should be under viewBox

Comment: Create an inner svg element with a viewBox and put the other elements under that or if the svg is embedded within html move it to another svg element.

Answer (score 0):

How about nested svg elements?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
    <image xlink:href="someimage.png" width="50" height="50"></image>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <!--other elements-->
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Structure of svg can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can display image by css background-image property of svg element instead of using image element.
This image is not affected by viewBox of svg element.

```
    svg{
        background-image:url("***.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:50px 50px;
    }
```